# Is a Java int always 32 bits?

Tags: java

Will Java's `int` always and everywhere be a 32 bit signed integer?

Comment: The number of bits used to represent an int value is the constant Integer.SIZE, which is specified as `public static final int SIZE = 32;` since Java 1.5.

Answer (score 132):

Yes, it's defined in [The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).

From [Section 4.2: Primitive Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2):

> The integral types are `byte`, `short`,
>   `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit,
>   16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed
>   two's-complement integers,
>   respectively, and `char`, whose values
>   are 16-bit unsigned integers
>   representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1).

And additionally from [Section 4.2.1: Integral Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1):

> The values of the integral types are
>   integers in the following ranges:
>
> - For byte, from -128 to 127, inclusive
> - For short, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive
> - For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive
> - For long, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive
> - For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

Answer (score 11):

`int`s are 32 bits. Should you need more, `long`s are 64 bits.

Answer (score 9):

Java 8 has added some support for unsigned integers.The primitive `int` is still signed, however some methods will interpret them as unsigned.

The following methods were added to the [Integer class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) in Java 8:

- compareUnsigned(int x, int y)
- divideUnsigned(int dividend, int divisor)
- parseUnsignedInt(String s)
- parseUnsignedInt(String s, int radix)
- remainderUnsigned(int dividend, int divisor)
- toUnsignedLong(int x)
- toUnsignedString(int i)
- toUnsignedString(int i, int radix)

Here is an example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int uint = Integer.parseUnsignedInt("4294967295");
    System.out.println(uint); // -1
    System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(uint)); // 4294967295
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As supplementary, if 64 bits long doesn't meet your requirement, try [java.math.BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

It's suitable for the situations where the number is beyond the range of 64 bit long.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    
    String max_long = "9223372036854775807";
    String min_long = "-9223372036854775808";
    
    BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(max_long);
    BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger(min_long);
    
    BigInteger sum = b1.add(b1);
    BigInteger difference = b2.subtract(b1);
    BigInteger product = b1.multiply(b2);
    BigInteger quotient = b1.divide(b1);
    
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
    System.out.println("The difference is: " + difference);
    System.out.println("The product is: " + product);
    System.out.println("The quotient is: " + quotient);
    
}
```

The output is:

The sum is: 18446744073709551614

The difference is: -18446744073709551615

The product is: -85070591730234615856620279821087277056

The quotient is: 1