# Iteration speed of int vs long

Tags: java, performance, optimization, jit

I have the following two programs:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++);
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (endTime - startTime) + " msecs");
```

and

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (long i = 0; i < N; i++);
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (endTime - startTime) + " msecs");
```

Note: the only difference is the type of the loop variable (`int` and `long`).

When I run this, the first program consistently prints between 0 and 16 msecs, regardless of the value of `N`. The second takes a lot longer. For `N == Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it runs in about 1800 msecs on my machine. The run time appears to be more or less linear in `N`.

So why is this?

I suppose the JIT-compiler optimizes the `int` loop to death. And for good reason, because obviously it doesn't do anything. But why doesn't it do so for the `long` loop as well?

A colleague thought we might be measuring the JIT compiler doing its work in the `long` loop, but since the run time seems to be linear in `N`, this probably isn't the case.

I'm using JDK 1.6.0 update 17:

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

I'm on Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Service Pack 2, with an Intel Core2 Quad CPU at 2.40GHz.

---

**DISCLAIMER**

I know that microbenchmarks aren't useful in production. I also know that `System.currentTimeMillis()` isn't as accurate as its name suggests. This is just something I noticed while fooling around, and I was simply curious as to why this happens; nothing more.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @Andrzej here, but if it's really just for curiosity's sake, you could use the PrintAssembly plugin to really look at the generated code: http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly

Comment: What happens if you run with the -Xint flag? This prevents Hotspot compiling, so you will get a better comparison.

Comment: @Steven: but with `-Xint` the result is *even less* meaningful for anything resembling real usage.

Comment: I'm curious at what PrintAssembly would show, if anyone wants to run it and post the results...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an interesting question, but to be honest I'm not convinced that considering Hotspot's behaviour here will yield useful information.  Any answers you do get are not going to be transferable in a general case (because we're looking at the optimisations that Hotspot performs in one specific situation), so they'll help you understand why one no-op is faster than another, *but they won't help you write faster "real" programs*.

It's also incredibly easy to write very misleading micro benchmarks around this sort of thing - see [this IBM DW article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225.html) for some of the common pitfalls, how to avoid them and some general commentary on what you're doing.

So really this is a "no comment" answer, but I think that's the only valid response.  A compile-time-trivial no-op loop doesn't *need* to be fast, so the compiler isn't optimised to be fast in some of these conditions.

Comment: You're right of course. The reason I'm asking is pure curiosity about something I noticed while fooling around; I don't intend to do this in a real program. :)

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using a 32-bit JVM. The results will be probably different with a 64bit JVM. In a 32-bit JVM an int can be mapped to a native 32-bit integer and be incremented with a single operation. The same doesn't hold for a long, which will require more operations to increment.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032982/is-a-java-int-always-32-bits) for a discussion about int and long sizes.

Comment: Good point. However, I'm using a 64 bits JVM. I'll update the question.

Comment: It will also be useful to post the operation system and some details about your hardware configuration (mainly the CPU).

Answer (score 3):

My guess - and it is only a guess - is this:

The JVM concludes that the first loop effectively does nothing, so it removes it entirely. No variable "escapes" from the for-loop.

In the second case, the loop also does nothing. But it might be that the JVM code that determines that the loop does nothing has a "if (type of i) == int" clause. In which case the optimisation to remove the do-nothing for-loop only works with int.

An optimisation that removes code has to be sure there are no side-effects. The JVM coders seem to have erred on the side of caution.

Answer (score 1):

Micro-benchmarking like this does not make a lot of sense, because the results depend a lot on the internal workings of the Hotspot JIT.

Also, note that the system clock values that you get with `System.currentTimeMillis()` don't have a 1 ms resolution on all operating systems. You can't use this to very accurately time very short duration events.

Have a look at this article, that explains why doing micro-benchmarks in Java is not as easy as most people think: [Anatomy of a flawed microbenchmark](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225.html)