# How FileInputStream and FileOutputStream Works in Java?

Tags: java, file

I'm reading about all input/output streams in java on [Java Tutorials Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html). Tutorials writer use this example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xanadu.txt File data:

```
In Xanadu did Kubla Khan
A stately pleasure-dome decree:
Where Alph, the sacred river, ran
Through caverns measureless to man
Down to a sunless sea.
```

Output to outagain.txt file:

```
In Xanadu did Kubla Khan
A stately pleasure-dome decree:
Where Alph, the sacred river, ran
Through caverns measureless to man
Down to a sunless sea.
```

1. Why do the writers use `int c` even if we are reading characters?
2. Why use `-1` in while condition?
3. How `out.write(c);` method convert `int` to again characters?

Comment: They are not characters, they are bytes. Are you familiar with the [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html)? There is an explanation for every class and every method in the standard Java libraries, including those of `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. It's important to learn from them when you are not sure why a method is invoked the way it is.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Java Tutorials Docs looks easy and user friendly, but java api docs looks like mess.. That's why I'm reading tutorials docs. Any how I will try to read from there.

Comment: They are not a source for learning how to program. They are a detailed explanation about each class. So every time you see a class used in a tutorial, you should look it up in the API docs. It's where the important information is.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ok Thanks.

Comment: 5 Upvotes for a "I don't want to read the JavaDoc, please do my research" question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1: Now I want to ask why writer use int c? even we are reading characters.

[`FileInputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read--) returns one byte of data as an `int`. This works because a byte can be represented as an `int` without loss of precision. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4659706/1743880) to understand why `int` is returned instead of `byte`.

> 2: The second why use -1 in while condition?

When the end of file is reached, -1 is returned.

> 3: How out.write(c); method convert int to again characters? that provide same output in outagain.txt file

[`FileOutputStream.write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write-int-) takes a byte parameter as an `int`. Since an `int` spans over more values than a byte, the 24 high-order bits of the given int are ignored, making it a byte-compatible value: an `int` in Java is [always 32 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032988/1743880). By removing the 24 high-order bits, you're down to a 8 bits value, i.e. a byte.

I suggest you read carefully the Javadocs for each of those method. As reference, they answer all of your questions:

[`read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--):

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

[`write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-int-):

> Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for write is that one byte is written to the output stream. The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.

Comment: Outstanding.. Everything Cleared..!!

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.` any example?

Comment: An `int` in Java is always 32 bits. By removing the 24 high-order bits, you're down to a 8 bits value, i.e. a byte.

Comment: quick question: after reading the bytes from files, where do those bytes are kept: in RAM, buffer. I mean how are bytes passed from inputstream to output stream?

Answer (score 1):

Just read the docs.

here is the read method docs 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()

> public int read()
>            throws IOException
>   Reads a byte of data from this input stream. This method blocks if no input is yet available.
>
> Specified by:
>   read in class InputStream
>
> Returns:
>   the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.

That int is a your next set of bytes data.
Now , here are the answers.

1) When you assign a char to an int, it denotes it's ascii number to the int.

*If you are interested, here us the list of chars and their ascii codes https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html*

2)-1 if the end of the file is reached. So that's a check to data exists or not.

3)When you send an ascii code to print writer, it's prints that corresponding char to the file.

Comment: @SURESH well explained. Just one question, how byte convert to int? implicitly?

Comment: Why are you talking about characters and PrintWriters where here we are dealing specifically with *byte streams*? There is no `char` here, and if the file is not in ASCII/UTF-8 etc. but in UTF-16 for example, what's being read will not necessarily be a character but a single byte.