# Terminate line without readLine() Method Java

Tags: java

As my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796097/how-fileinputstream-and-fileoutputstream-works-in-java) I used `read()` from `java.io.FileInputStream` and `read();` provide output in same line without line terminated. After that I used `readLine()` from `java.io.BufferedReader` and got output in different line with line terminated. I explored `readLine()` method and I got this line from [Java API Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--)

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

After reading above quote from Java Docs, I modify my `read();` method program to terminate line without `readLine()` method. But failed,

**Here is the Modified code.**(that I want to use for line terminated)

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BoxDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                if((char)c=='\r' || (char)c=='\n') {
                    out.write('\n');
                } else {
                    out.write(c);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is** `readLine();` method code that give output with line terminated.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BoxDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader inputStream = null;
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt"));

            String l;
            while ((l = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                outputStream.println(l);
            }
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting...?

Comment: @redflar3 I'm not getting output with line terminated. Output still in one line.

Comment: where did you view the file? if notepad, it wont recognize `\n` as new line.. View in Notepad++ or any advanced editor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reference, here's the output of your first code with the same `xanadu.txt` file as your last question:

Input:

```
In Xanadu did Kubla Khan
A stately pleasure-dome decree:
Where Alph, the sacred river, ran
Through caverns measureless to man
Down to a sunless sea.
```

Output:

```
In Xanadu did Kubla Khan

A stately pleasure-dome decree:

Where Alph, the sacred river, ran

Through caverns measureless to man

Down to a sunless sea.
```

So there's a redundant line break somewhere. This comes from the following if condition:

```
if((char)c=='\r' || (char)c=='\n') {
    out.write('\n');
```

I'm guessing you are running this on a Windows machine where the line terminator is `\r\n`, so the characters `\r` and `\n` are actually both read, resulting in `\n` being written twice.

Again, since you seem to be using Windows, depending on your editor, it might not format `\n` as line breaks and outputs everything on a single line.

You can correct this by writing

```
out.write('\r');
out.write('\n');
```

explicitely.

With having said that, I do not recommend you to use this. You should use `System.lineSeparator()` where possible, as this results in the system dependant correct line separator.

Comment: reference output just due to Stackoverflow, but in text file it is in one line.

Comment: how I can use `System.lineSeparator()` in `write()`? becuase I want line Terminated in txt file.